# DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashSet len:1 Flutter

Tags: flutter, dio

I want to print data from the api but i am getting this error below:
DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500]

Check the screenshot below from postman, It is working well.

Below is my code, I need help. I get error when I call this function below:

```
Future<void> signInData([data]) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String token = prefs.getString('token') ?? "";

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('$_baseUrl/api/gateway',
          data: {
            {
              "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
              "PlatformId": "ios",
              "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
              "VinNumber": VINumber
            }
          },
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
          }));
      print(response.data);
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        // call your refresh token api here and save it in shared preference
        await getToken();
        signInData(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey i think you have extra { in data: of _dio.post method or try to print response.data.toString()

Comment: Oh thanks man, I just saw it now.

Comment: I am now getting this error  DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [500], do you perhaps know what might cause this?

Comment: this is internal server error, you need to check this api in postman first

Comment: try data like  jsonEncode({
              "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
              "PlatformId": "ios",
              "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
              "VinNumber": VINumber
            })

Comment: jsonEncode gives an error

Comment: may i know what is error and in postman how you are posting your data

Comment: Dude crop api base url from postman screenshot

Comment: Eish thanks for that man, I removed it but I am sure you have seen the response right

Comment: Yes i could see

Answer (score 0):

Hey remove extra `{` from data inside post method like below -

```
Future<void> signInData([data]) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String token = prefs.getString('token') ?? "";

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('$_baseUrl/api/gateway',
          data: {
              "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
              "PlatformId": "ios",
              "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
              "VinNumber": VINumber            
          },
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
          }));
      print(response.data.toString());
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        // call your refresh token api here and save it in shared preference
        await getToken();
        signInData(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: token is printed like this {Token: eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxL} don't you think maybe, it takes the string "token" also with the token, thus returning 500, because we only need from "ey........", right or am I missing it?

Comment: Hey you need to parse this  String json  = '{"Token": "eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxL"}';
    print(jsonDecode(token)["Token"]);

Comment: await prefs.setString("token", jsonEncode(r.data["Token"]));    please check this when I save the token, is this alright?

Comment: await prefs.setString("token",  r.data["Token"]);   this will work as r.data is already a map so you can get value directly by using key and don’t need to jsonEncode or Decode

Comment: print your token after you save it ti confirm it

Comment: It gives this error I/flutter (31275): Instance of 'SharedPreferences'

Comment: Managed to fix that, I was printing the incorrect way, this is how I got the token I saved; print(prefs.getString("token"));

Comment: I hope issue is fix now

Comment: Yes, it does, I can get data now.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can accept my answer and upvote it